# Increase the speed for $lookup with $match in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

Collection **Product** data:

```
 item_id |  item  |    desc    |  req
---------------------------------------
   101   |  book  |  product1  |   20
   103   |  copy  |  product3  |   30
   102   | eraser |  product2  |   10
   104   |  pen   |  product4  |   20
                ....
```

Collection **Stock** data:

```
 item_id | quantity | price |  type
-------------------------------------
   101   |    20    |  200  |  typeA
   103   |    50    |  100  |  typeA
   102   |    30    |  50   |  typeC
   104   |    40    |  80   |  typeB
                ....
```

Mongo query:

```
db.Product.createIndex({ 'item_id': 1 });
db.Product.aggregate([
        {'$sort': {'item_id': 1}},
        {'$lookup': {
          'from': 'Stock,
          'as': 'idList'
          'let': { 'prod_id': '$item_id' },
          'pipeline': [
            {'$match': {'$expr': {'$eq': ['$item_id', '$$prod_id']}}}
            { $project: { 'quantity ': 1, 'price': 1}},
          ]
        }},
        {'$match': {'idList': {'$ne': []}}},
        {'$project': {'item_id': 1, 'quantity ': 1, 'desc': 1, 
           'quantity ': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$idList.quantity ', 0]}, 
           'price': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$idList.price', 0]}}},
        {'$match': {'$or': [{'item_id': {'$in': [101, 103]}}, 
          {'item': {'$regex': 'bo', '$options': '$i'}}, {'quantity': {'$in': [20, 10]}}, 
          {'price': {'$in': [200, 50]}}]}}, 
        {'$facet': {
           'itemCount': [{'$count': 'item_id'}], 
           'itemDetails': [
              {'$sort': {'quantity': 1, 'item_id': 1}}, 
              {'$skip': 0}, {'$limit': 10}
          ]}}
      ]);
```

I am joining these two collections Product and Stock with **$lookup** by using the index as I am sorting the collection with **item_id** at first. After getting the joined collection data I need to apply filter and accordingly, get count and details through **$facet**, with the details limiting to 10 records.

It is working fine for less records but taking more than 30 seconds with 10000 records even after providing the index.
How to increase the performance of lookup in the query which will also take less time?

Answer (score 0):

Questions like these are best answered when additional information is provided. Most helpful is the verbose explain plan (`.explain("allPlansExecution")`) for the operation along with the indexes for all relevant collections (`.getIndexes()`). In the absence of that, here are some observations based on the aggregation pipeline and the description provided in the question.

It is unclear if the `{ item_id: 1 }` index and preceding `$sort` provide any value here. Indexes provided the most value when the query is retrieving a small subset of results relative to the overall size of the collection. That does not *appear* to be the case here (with one question about this below). Presently the  aggregation reads all documents from the source (`Product`) collection. Therefore having the index and forcing it's usage with the preceding `$sort` is probably *harming* the operation by slowing it down. The extra overhead of doing a full index scan on top of randomly accessing the data from the collection is going to be slower than just doing a full collection scan to begin with. You can probably drop this index and remove the `$sort` as a first step.

Next, you need to be sure to have the appropriate index on the `Stock` collection. That index should at least be one that starts with the `item_id` field since that is the field used for matching. You might consider creating a compound index on `{ item_id: 1, quantity: 1, price: 1}`. This would allow the lookup to be fully covered by the index (avoiding retrieval of documents themselves). How much benefit is provided by avoiding fetching documents depends on many factors, but it is critically important to at least have an index that allows the documents to quickly be identified by their `item_id`.

For the second `$match`, it seems there's a bracket or two that is out of place. Is this the intended shape of that filter?

```
  {
    '$or': [
      { item_id: { '$in': [ 101, 103 ] } },
      { item: { '$regex': 'bo', '$options': '$i' } },
      { quantity: { '$in': [ 20, 10 ] } },
      { price: { '$in': [ 200, 50 ] } }
    ]
  }
```

If so, it seems like a bit of a strange filter. You have two specific `item_id`s that you want to return, but you're *also* looking to retrieve other entries based on the name of the item, the quantity in stock, or the price?

If that is not the correct logic, and you only want to retrieve entries that have a specific `item_id`, then you should promote that to a `$match` as the very first stage of the pipeline. Along with an index beginning with the `item_id` field (on both collections) the operation would run very quickly.'

You might also consider running two different aggregations, one to get the data and one to get the count, rather than using `$facet` at the end. It may allow each to execute more efficiently than running them together.

There are a few other simplifications you could make to the pipeline, but starting with the stuff above is probably the most likely to meaningfully improve performance.

---

All of this said, there is an important question to ask. Is there a strong reason for this related data in two separate collections/documents? Would it make sense to just combine them into a single one therefore forever eliminating the need to do the `$lookup` altogether?

---

Edit to address some of the comments.

Below I will demonstrate *an approach* that probably improves performance for this operation with the given schema. But I want to reiterate caution towards just jumping in to use it straightaway. I have a suspicion that you are setting yourself to repeatedly deal with friction related to this schema.

Because you want to retrieve data that matches certain conditions from one collection *or* another, there is no index or method to do this efficiently directly. This is because even if the document in `Product` does not have the right `item_id` (for example), the generated object after joining with the associated document in the `Stock` collection may have a correct value of (for example) `price`. That means that you would have to generate the combined objects for *all* documents from `Product` before you could filter anything.

The way to approach that is to issue "two queries", one to efficiently find the items based on the filters to the `Product` collection and the other (doing a 'reverse' `$lookup`) to efficiently retrieve the items based on the `Stock` filters. This could be done as two separate queries from the client, or you could use the `$unionWith` stage to issue a single query from the client that logically does both of these things on the database.

Your existing approach is demonstrated [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R_sJlkxVudZ). The alternative described above is demonstrated [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FZOsmdPX-vW). Apart from the `_id` value, you'll notice that the output is identical. Here are some observations:

- You could make them have identical `_id` values, it just makes the solution a little more verbose.  Unclear if that's important or not. The discrepancy is simply caused by the fact that this approach has to do a `$lookup` in both directions.
- You'll want to make several different indexes to support this operation efficiently. While not exactly, one on each of the filtered fields is a good place to start.
- This approach assumes a 1:1 relationship between these collections. Your original pipeline implies the same.

Because of that last point - it really feels likely that you should combine these documents into a single collection. This would remove the need to `$lookup` entirely, simplifying the document identification down to a single `$match` with a `$or` clause.

Note also that [case insensitive regex commands cannot use indexes efficiently](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use). So even if you were to make the other associated changes (either to the aggregation or by changing the schema), you would still need to separately adjust how you are performing this text search. If you were to just put an index on the field then every query will effectively perform a full index scan to check for matching string values.

Finally, it is true to say that using indexes *efficiently* is usually the first step toward improving the performance of an operation. But forcing a full index scan to then fetch all of the documents is the opposite of using an index efficiently. That's why dropping the index and the `$sort` from your original pipeline would improve the performance (though likely not nearly enough for the operation to be usable and scalable).

Comment: thanks for noticing the typo, I already edited that.  And I use ` $match` after `$lookup` as there, I'm using `$or` which could be done only with the data from joined table. And as for the index, I chose `item_id` as it's unique. I sorted it to use index in the query by **explain** with `"stage" : "IXSCAN"` , else if I'm not sorting it's showing `"stage" : "COLLSCAN"`.

Comment: Using an index in this particular situation is _bad_ and not what you want. You are _already_ scanning all of the data so adding a full index scan on top of that will slow it down further. If the logic in the second `$match` is really what you want, then this query is going to be inefficient and slow. That logic accepts 1 of 4 different predicate values which are coming from _different_ collections. It will have to do a full collection scan to retrieve all documents from `Product` (such as `102` `eraser`) since it may have a matching `quantity` or `price` from `Stock`

Comment: As lots of documents suggested to use index with `$lookup` for lesser response time I was sorting with *item_id*, after creating index on it. And, actually that's the requirement where I need to `$match` from different collections' data where I can use `$or`, hence it's taking so time as mentioned. Can you suggest any other method to get the same result with less time?

Comment: Updated my answer. I'd strongly recommend combining the collections into a single one if they currently have a 1:1 relationship. Otherwise working with the data will be complex throughout the lifespan of this project.